# bind object with lists to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have the following class which holds some Lists:

```
public class Trajectory
{
    public List<double> Radii { get; set; }
    public List<double> Phis  { get; set; }
}
```

And I want a DataGrid which looks like that:

```
| Radii | Phis |
----------------
|  4.5  |  10  |
|  5.5  |  20  |
|  6.5  |  30  |
|  7.5  |  40  |
```

What I have done so far is having two `DataGrid`s in my xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TrajectoryRadiiDataGrid">
<DataGrid x:Name="TrajectoryPhiDataGrid"/>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
Trajectory trajectory = new Trajectory() { Radii = new List<double>() { 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5 }, Phis = new List<double>() { 10, 20, 30, 40} };

DataGridTextColumn radiusColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
radiusColumn.Header = "Radii";
radiusColumn.Binding = new Binding("");
TrajectoryRadiiDataGrid.Columns.Add(radiusColumn);
TrajectoryRadiiDataGrid.ItemsSource = trajectory.Radii;

DataGridTextColumn phiColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
phiColumn.Header = "Phis";
phiColumn.Binding = new Binding("");
TrajectoryPhiDataGrid.Columns.Add(phiColumn);
TrajectoryPhiDataGrid.ItemsSource = trajectory.Phis;
```

But this can't be the Holy Grail!

And a main drawback: This doesn't allow for TwoWay Binding, because this would need a Path!

Is there any possiblity to have **one** `DataGrid` for the whole object which allows TwoWay Binding?

**Important**: This is a very simple model. I know that I could make a List of Points.

```
public class Trajectory
{
    public List<Point> points { get; set; }
}
```

And bind that list to the DataGrid. *But this is not possible in my application!*

So the question is: **How to bind two lists to a DataGrid?**

Comment: Make a `Radius` class and make a list of those.

Comment: @SLaks: please see my Edits at the bottom.

Comment: @Rico-E, easiest would be to create some `RadiiPhis` view model to store both properties, merge both lists and bind that. Then split it when you need separate values.

Comment: @dkozl: This is almost identical to that `List<Point>`...

Comment: @Rico-E, problem is that `Point` is a struct (value type) so when WPF will create items from binding it will copy whole struct instead of only reference so when you change in `DataGrid` it will change copy and not `Point` in your list. Two way binding won't be possible

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
DT.Columns.Add ("Radii");
DT.Columns.Add ("Phis");

if (Radii.Count == Phis.Count ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Radii.Count; i++ ) {
         DT.Columns.Rows.Add(new String[] {Radii[i].ToString(), Phis[i].ToString()})
    }
}

DataGrid DG = new DataGrid();
DG.ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView;
```

Second Question:

```
 DataRow row = (DataRow)DG.ItemContainerGenerator.Items[i];
 var V1 = row.Column["Radii"]
 var V2 = row.Column["Phis"]
 // Store them in a new object
 // if you wanna compare data use a loop or Linq
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for displaying the information. But how about TwoWay Binding? How can I make it possible to edit the data in the Grid and see those changes in my `trajectory` variable?

Comment: To do that, get the row count of the table, read each row using the type DataRow, then you will have two elements in each DataRow, you can store them in a new object, when done, make a comparison with the original object using Linq or maybe simple foeach loops.

Comment: Ahmm... Could you please give me a short code example for that? Beacuse I don't see where the binding happens...

Comment: That is what I would do, coz it's the simplest way in my opinion. Some people may wanna go for a more advanced method, there's more than a solution to a single problem. But this still does the trick :)

Comment: But when do I now, that someone changed the data in the Grid? Should I just add a handler to `CellEditEnding`-event of the `DataGrid`, or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @Rico-E: The person that changes the grid definitely won't leave it and then close the program, something must be performed on the data, like for example when data is changed submit it to the system (or server), then you know that something has happened. You don't necessarily need to write an event handler, but if you do, it wouldn't free of free of benefits.

Comment: Well... I forgot to mention, that the List `Radii` and the List `Phis` are independent from each other. Is it possible to have a DataGrid whose columns are different in length?